# How does AndFix patch methods?

Tags: android, dalvik

I learned recently of an Android library [AndFix](https://github.com/alibaba/AndFix) which allows for live method patching. Now, as far as I know, Dalvik does not allow runtime manipulation of bytecode or dex.

Can someone provide a good explanation on how [AndFix](https://github.com/alibaba/AndFix) does live patching?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the sources, you can see the patch mechanism for Dalvik [here](https://github.com/alibaba/AndFix/blob/master/jni/dalvik/dalvik_method_replace.cpp#L196). The `dalvik_replaceMethod()` function is modifying the internal Dalvik state, changing the `Method` struct to point to a replacement method.

It doesn't modify the DEX on disk or in memory, just routes the method calls to a replacement method.  This approach is highly version-dependent, as changes to `Method` or the way methods work will break things.  Dalvik hasn't changed much since mid-2011, which makes it easy, but if you look at the nearby "art" directory you can see different implementations for each major version of Android.